# PosterDirectory returns null

Tags: c#, webforms

I declared the variable PosterDirectory here

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnectionString());
String PosterDirectory;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Role"].ToString() != "Admin")
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }



    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetEvent(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["EventID"].ToString()));
    }


}
```

Supposedly PosterDirectory would be given a value within the GetEvent function.

```
void GetEvent(int EventID)
{

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        "select * from event where EventID = @EventID", con);
    com.Parameters.Add("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EventID;
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Fill in the input fields based on the EventID
        txtName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
        txtVenue.Text = reader["Venue"].ToString();
        txtStreet.Text = reader["Street"].ToString();
        txtCity.Text = reader["City"].ToString();
        txtCountry.Text = reader["Country"].ToString();
        txtMap.Text = reader["Map"].ToString();
        txtStartDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateTimeStarted"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        txtStartTime.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateTimeStarted"].ToString()).TimeOfDay.ToString();
        txtEndDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateTimeEnded"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        txtEndTime.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateTimeEnded"].ToString()).TimeOfDay.ToString();
        PosterDirectory = reader["Poster"].ToString();
        txtDesciption.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();

    }
    con.Close();
}
```

I will use the String PosterDirectory later on for my SQL Parameter to retrieve the filepath of a photo.

```
 protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the Date and Time Strings
    DateTime DateStarted = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text);
    TimeSpan TimeStarted = TimeSpan.Parse(txtStartTime.Text);
    DateTime DateEnded = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text);
    TimeSpan TimeEnded = TimeSpan.Parse(txtEndTime.Text);

    DateTime DateTimeStarted = DateStarted + TimeStarted;
    DateTime DateTimeEnded = DateEnded + TimeEnded;

    //Get the DateTimeCreated
    DateTime DateTimeLastUpdated;

    con.Open();
    //if (fuPoster.HasFile)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
            "update event set Name=@Name, Venue=@Venue, Street=@Street, City=@City, Country=@Country, Map=@Map, DateTimeStarted=@DateTimeStarted, DateTimeEnded=@DateTimeEnded, DateTimeUpdated=@DateTimeUpdated, Poster=@Poster, Description=@Description where EventID=@EventID",
            con);
        com.Parameters.Add("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["EventID"].ToString());
        com.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Venue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtVenue.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStreet.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCountry.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Map", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMap.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeStarted", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimeStarted;
        com.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeEnded", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimeEnded;
        com.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeUpdated", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        DateTimeLastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

        if (fuPoster.HasFile)
        {
            com.Parameters.Add("@Poster", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "images/" + fuPoster.FileName;
            fuPoster.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/" + fuPoster.FileName));
        }
        else
        {
            com.Parameters.Add("@Poster", SqlDbType.Text).Value = PosterDirectory;

        }
        com.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtDesciption.Text;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        //Auditing Event
        AuditEvent(DateTimeLastUpdated);

        Response.Redirect("Event.aspx");
    }
    //else
    //{
    //    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
    //        "update event set Name=@Name, Venue=@Venue, Street=@Street, City=@City, Country=@Country, Map=@Map, DateTimeStarted=@DateTimeStarted, DateTimeEnded=@DateTimeEnded, DateTimeUpdated=@DateTimeUpdated, Description=@Description where EventID=@EventID",
    //        con);
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["EventID"].ToString());
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@Venue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtVenue.Text;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStreet.Text;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCountry.Text;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@Map", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMap.Text;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeStarted", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimeStarted;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeEnded", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimeEnded;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeUpdated", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    //    com.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtDesciption.Text;
    //    DateTimeLastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    //    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //    con.Close();

    //    //Auditing Event
    //    AuditEvent(DateTimeLastUpdated);

    //    Response.Redirect("Event.aspx");
    //}
}
```

Comment: where/when do you use it? an asp.net web `Form` class is only valid for a single request.

Comment: Hold on Daniel, I'll add the event/trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members aren't persisted between requests. The `Form` class is only valid for a single request.

For context, read up on the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

You could put your value into a hidden form field or the view state.